# How can I disable body onload when the browser back button is used

Tags: onload, back-button, disable

We use the body onload function to initialize selections on a form
if the user modifies those selections and submits the form often the want to click back to change a selection and submit the form again.

When the user clicks back the form is clearly resetting form the onload function.
We desire the user to be able to use the back button to see their chosen selections.

We have tried several methods of variables to run once and disabling the onload in the submit button. Nothing has been successful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this from your onload function before clearing the form:

```
function isBackForward() {
  if (typeof performance === "object") {
    // Use the newer API if available.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming
    if (typeof performance.getEntriesByType === "function") {
      var entries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
      if (entries.length === 1) {
        if (entries[0].type === "back_forward") {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        // unable to determine
        return void(0); // undefined
      }
    // Try the older deprecated API instead
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation
    } else if (typeof performance.navigation === "object") {
      if (performance.navigation.type === performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      // unable to determine
      return void(0); // undefined
    }
  } else {
    // unable to determine
    return void(0); // undefined
  }
}
```

This function will return true if back or forward was used, undefined if the browser doesn't support the needed apis to determine that, or false if it was another type of navigation.

Unfortunately this alone will not work in Safari. For Safari, you could set a state value in sessionStorage (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for the page when the submit button is pressed, and then check for it before clearing the form.